# ASP.NET MVC: Cannot convert ObjectQuery -> Linq.IQueryable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i must be doing something wrong or maybe i don't get this. I'm trying to fill 'PropAllMenus' (that has a bunch of properties) with data coming from my entity framework. However, when doing the conversion trough a function i get a 'InvaldCastExeption' in my 'WeekMenuRepository'. Here is the code:

## PropAllMenus

```
Public Class PropAllMenus

    Private _MenuID As Integer
    Public Property MenuID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _MenuID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _MenuID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _DaypartID As Integer
    Public Property DaypartID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _DaypartID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _DaypartID = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

## WeekMenuRepository

```
Private _db As New EDMWeekmenuEntities()
    Public Function ListAllMenus() As IQueryable(Of PropAllMenus) Implements IWeekMenuRepository.ListAllMenus
        Dim result = From p In _db.Menus _
                     Select p
        Return result

    End Function
```

## HomeController

```
Dim DoThings As New WeekMenuRepository()
     Function Index() As ActionResult

            Return View(DoThings.ListAllMenus().ToList)

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

PropAllMenus isn't an entity type, so the EF can't implicitly convert an entity type like Menu to it.

In other words, your function result type is `IQueryable(Of PropAllMenus)`, but your query is returning something like `ObjectQuery(Of Menu)`. If you could change your query to return `ObjectQuery(Of PropAllMenus)` then the implicit cast (when you call Return) to IQueryable would work.

You need to do something like:

```
    Dim result = From p In _db.Menus _
                 Select New PropAllMenus With
                 {
                     .MenuId = p.MenuId,
                     .Name = p.Name,
                     // etc.
                 }
```

By the way, I noticed that you have asked 6 questions, but have never accepted any answers, nor uploaded anything. You should press the "up arrow" next to any answers which you find helpful, and press the "checkmark" icon next to the single most helpful answer for a question you've asked. It's a way of saying "thank you."